# OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, database-connection

I'm running through the Flask tutorial for a simple blog/cms and I can't seem to open/create a database.

I'm currently on Windows 7, when I go to view the app I get a sqlite3.OperationalError
OperationalError: unable to open database file error on the webpage. I've tried googling the issue but I haven't been able to fix it. I assume it has to do with that I'm using Windows. Can anyone help?

```
DATABASE = 'C:\Users\Brad\Documents\flaskr\flaskr.db'

def connect_db():
return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
       with app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape your string properly:

```
DATABASE = 'C:\\Users\\Brad\\Documents\\flaskr\\flaskr.db'
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @AllofHumanity: Windows understands forward slashes just fine, so you can use them as well. This will also make your code more compatible (well, besides the hard-coded parts, obviously). You might want to use `os.path.join` as well.